# Linux kernel function returns 1 instead of EINVAL

Tags: c++, c, linux-kernel, kernel, system-calls

I'm trying to add a new system call to linux kernel:

```
asmlinkage long sys_set_status(int status) {
    if ((status != 0) && (status != 1))
        return -EINVAL; //-22
    current->status = status;
    return 0;
}
```

in syscall_64.tbl it is declared:

```
334 common  set_status      sys_set_status
```

in syscalls.h it is declared:

```
asmlinkage long sys_set_status(int status);
```

but when i test the return value:

```
int set_status(int status) {
    long r = syscall(334, status);
    return (int)r;
}

int main() {
    int res = set_status(-1); //illegal status, should return -EINVAL whish is -22
    cout << "return value is: " << res << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

i get:

> return value is: -1

Comment: It seems it's not your function that's being called since your function can only return one of `0` and `-22`.

Comment: What is `errno` after the call? In your driver where do you insert the pointer to your handler function? Can you verify that the table entry is set up correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `long r = syscall(334, status);`

From [man syscall](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscall.2.html):

> The return value is defined by the system call being invoked.  In
> general, a 0 return value indicates success.  A -1 return value
> indicates an error, and an error number is stored in errno.

You are *not* calling the system call directly, you are calling it via the `libc` `syscall` wrapper, which performs approximately this:

```
int syscall(num, ...)
{
  /* architecture-specific code to put system call number and args into
     appropriate registers */
  /* arch-specific code to execute the system call instruction */
  int rc = /* arch-specific code to get the result of the system call */ ;
  if (rc < 0) { errno = -rc; return -1; }
  return 0;
}
```

If you don't want this translation to happen, you would have to perform the architecture-specific parts yourself (in assembly), and then you would have the *actual* system call return value.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in **Employed Russian**'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72333731/5264491), negative return values from system calls get converted to a return value of -1 by the system call wrapper functions in *libc* and `errno` is set. So the return value of -1 is expected and the value of `errno` should be checked.

It is likely that `errno` will be set to `ENOSYS` rather than `EINVAL` because the kernel syscall code has been written in the old format that does work on most 64-bit kernels. The kernel code for the system call should be updated to use the `SYSCALL_DEFINE1` wrapper macro (because the syscall has 1 parameter) as shown below:

```
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
```

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE1(set_status, int, status)
{
    if ((status != 0) && (status != 1))
        return -EINVAL; //-22
    current->status = status;
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Actually, if that is the problem, the kernel should fail to link due to undefined symbols. But you should use the new format anyway (if possible, and probably not for kernels released before 2009).

I'm not sure what the point of this syscall is anyway. The task state ought to be set back to 0 when the syscall exits back to userland.